# CeRun.exe not launching batch file on WinCE

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, windows-ce, windows-mobile-5.0

I'm trying to launch batch file on my WinCE device (device for proceeding payment transactions) with utility CeRun.exe from my PC(Windows 10)

File cerunner.dll (which is required to run cerun.exe on device) is in *CE:\Windows* folder.
After launching `Call CeRun.exe -b "CE:\rename_f.bat"` it returns error

> cerun: Failed to execute program (193)

rename_f.bat code:

```
@echo off 

echo Date is 06-06-2018 
move "Flash Disk\ECRO_EJ" "Flash Disk\ECRO_EJ_06-06-2018" 
move "SDMMC Storage Card\ECRO_EJ" "SDMMC Storage Card\ECRO_EJ_06-06-2018" 

PAUSE
```

Thank You for help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by calling cmd.exe on WinCE device from the PC batch script!

```
Call cerun.exe "CE:\Windows\cmd.exe" /c "\rename_f.bat"
```

Comment: Cause CeRun can not start a bat file directly.